# Can we add CV-qualifiers to the arguments of main?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

As far as I know, in C or C++, the signature of `main` should either be `int main(void)` (`void` is optional in C++) or `int main(int, char**)`. However, the following code compiles with no warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`) in gcc/g++/clang/clang++

```
int main(int, const char * const * const argv){}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b98ac599e5d50c4a)

Is the code above legal? In other words, can we add CV-qualifiers to the arguments of `main`, or is this just an extension of the compiler that requires no diagnostic?

Comment: @STF I see that, but do you have some standard reference? As far as I remember (and I don't have the standard in front of me now), the signature is mandated to `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`, or, syntactic sugar, `int main(int, char* [])`.

Comment: @Galik Why? The pointers are not implicitly convertible, it's not standard array-to-pointer decay. So the CV-quals should be part of the signature. Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: The last `const` is OK because it doesn't change the function type, because it's top level. The first two `const`s are not OK. Note: for the formally pedantic there's a difference between a hosted and free-standing implementation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's what I thought too, top level is ignored, but the rest shouldn't.

Comment: @vsoftco You're right it does change the signature, soz :)

Comment: The Standard *allows* the implementation to accept any signature it likes it only *mandates* the two presented in question.

Comment: @Galik Can you perhaps post this comment as an answer with a standard quote if you have the time? I think it will be useful for some other users (at least I didn't find a suitable dupe until now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `C++11` Standard allows the implementation to accept any signature it likes it only mandates the two presented in question. It must also have a return type of `int`.

> **3.6.1 Main Function** [basic.start.main]
>
> **2** An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall
>   allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ...
> */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ...
> */ }
> ```

So to address the main question:

> **Can we add CV-qualifiers to the arguments of main?**

We can *if the implementation supports it* but if we do then the code is less likely to be portable.

The code will only be fully portable if it adds (at most) *cv qualifiers* to the parameter variable itself, not its pointed-to types:

```
// still portable, same signature as int main(int, char**)
int main(int, char** const argv); 

// not portable
int main(int, char* const* argv); 

// not portable
int main(int, const char** argv);
```

Comment: This is literally correct because the signature of a function does not include the return type (which must be `int` for `main`).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you saying that *but otherwise its type is implementation-defined* refers to the return type?

Comment: The *type* of a function includes the return type. The *signature* is what the linker considers: " name, parameter type list (8.3.5), and enclosing namespace (if any)" (from C++14 §1.3.17). §3.6.1 talks about the function type sans the return type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks!

Comment: I think this answer would be even better ( :) ) if included discussion of what CV-qualifiers can be added for completely portable code.

Comment: *"The code will only be fully portable if it adds (at most) cv qualifiers to the parameter variable itself, not its pointed-to types"*: In other words, top-CV qualifiers are discarded, as for any other function signature. Great answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Remember that C and C++ are two distinct languages. The answer happens to be pretty much the same for both, but it's worth covering what the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says as well -- especially given the language-lawyer tag.  The link is to the N1570 draft of C11.

Section 5.1.2.2.1 covers the definition of `main` for hosted implementations:

> The function called at program startup is named **`main`**. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of **`int`** and with no parameters:
>
> **`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`**
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as **`argc`** and **`argv`**,
>   though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in
>   which they are declared):
>
> **`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`**
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

A definition with added `const` or `volatile` qualifiers is not equivalent to the forms shown, so an implementation is not obliged to accept it. But since that section is not a *constraint*, an implementation is not required to complain about it either.  And in particular, if an implementation documents that it accepts `const` and/or `volatile` qualifiers, then they're perfectly valid *for that implementation*.

(In practice, most compilers probably won't complain.)

Note that this applies only to *hosted implementations*.  For a *freestanding implementation* (typically for an embedded target with no OS):

> ... the name and type of the function called at program
>   startup are implementation-defined.

(5.1.2.1 paragraph 1) which means that there are *no* portable definitions of the main function for freestanding implementations (it needn't even be called `main`).

Comment: Thanks for the standard quotes!